# cxf wsdl2java generates a single class with all elements as inner static classes

Tags: java, cxf, wsdl2java

We're trying to generate classes from a wsdl. For similar projects before, the wsdl2java has generated a separate class for each request/response element in defined in the xsd's. However, in this case we only get a single class for the request and a single class for the response, and within these classes, all the elements are generated as static inner classes. There are a lot of parameters in the request/response so these two classes get huge. Additionally, one of the classes are generated twice so we get a duplicate class issue as well.

Not sure if it matters, but we are using the -b option with a custom.xml:

```
<jaxws:bindings
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
  <enableWrapperStyle>false</enableWrapperStyle>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Any suggestions on how to get the classes separated in it's own files? Or does it seem like an issue with the wsdl/xsd resources?

Comment: when used on the cli, you'd use the -u flag (Unpacks the databinding classes).

Comment: There's no -u flag for the cxf wsdl2java. I guess you mean the Axis2 version? Would prefer to only use cxf, but maybe I should try to use another tool if I get stuck with this issue.